# How to format and calculate date based on timezone in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

How to format and calculate the date based on timezone .Consider the example below

$date = "2015-12-16 07:00:00";
$timeZonePassed = "CET";

Now my function should return me a date in CET format like mm.dd.yy h.i.s. As i am doing this $dateConv->format($dateFormat) , my date is always displayed as mm/dd/yy but my expectation it should calculate time based on the timezone and display the date format based on timezone.

```
function formatDate($date, $timeZonePassed) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . "UTC")); 
    $dateFormat ='m/d/Y h:i A';
    $dateConv = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
    $dateConv->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timeZonePassed);
    return $dateConv->format($dateFormat);
}
```

Comment: The format for date display will be based on the format mask that you use, which you're explicitly setting via `$dateFormat ='m/d/Y h:i A';`.... PHP will not choose a format for you, whether based on timezone or not, so your expectation is wrong

Comment: A time zone isn't a format. They're entirely separate concepts. I'd also strongly recommend that you use time zone IDs (e.g. "Europe/Paris") rather than the abbreviations for "partial" zones. For example, Europe/London observes BST half the year and GMT half the year. Neither of these are the time zone - Europe/London is.

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thanks. Is there a way to know date format based on timezone in php?

Comment: Not based purely on timezone, because there isn't a standardized format for timezones.... CET (Central European Time) is used in Albania, Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Bosnia-Herzegovina, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, France, Germany, Gibraltar, Hungary, Italy, Kosovo, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malta, Monaco, Montenegro, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Republic of Macedonia, San Marino, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland and the Vatican not to mention Algeria and Tunisia as well - and those countries don't all use the same format for dates/times.

Comment: e.g. Algeria uses `dd/mm/yyyy`;Poland uses either `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`; Spain uses `dd/mm/yyyy` but the Basque regions of Spain use `yyyy.mm.dd`, etc; so there isn't even a standard format by country, never mind by timezone

Comment: You may be better allowing your users to choose the format that they want to see, and using a mask based on their choice

Comment: @MarkBaker In that case , when i do this $dateConv->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("CET"); it will just convert the UTC date to CET date ,but not the format right?

Comment: It converts the DateTime object to CET, the DateTime object has no implicit format; simply an internal representation.... it's entirely up to you to use the `format()` method with a format mask of your choice to return a formatted string containing that date/time value

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks a lot for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function formatDate($date, $timeZonePassed) {

$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); 
$dateConv = new DateTime( $dates, $UTC  );
$dateFormat ='m/d/Y h:i A';

$dateConv->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timeZonePassed));
return $dateConv->format($dateFormat);
}
```

work fine this cide useful for you